# Do we need more entries in "This question belongs on another site..."?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Some of the questions I vote to close are under the *"This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network"* category.

Currently I only have 3 entries to choose from:

> wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com
>
> stackoverflow.com
>
> webmasters.stackexchange.com

But sometimes I come across questions that fit in neither of above. For example, some questions are about server configuration, NGINX errors, Apache rewrites, which belong to ServerFault. Not to mention the rare questions that belong to SuperUser (question about problem in Chrome, Firefox, etc).

Is it possible to add these to the list too?

If so, where should I post this request?

Comment: _"…which belong to ServerFault…"_ … I would not say that those belong to SF in all cases. Gentle reminder: This site is about server administration as well.

Comment: Thanks. But these type of questions often get flagged as off-topic.

Comment: Which should not be the case for most of them. I hope you keep open what is worth being kept open.

Comment: While I generally agree, don't you think adding more sites will make this even more confusing? Assuming people whose questions get closed for this reason are (relatively) new to the StackExchange network, giving them more choices might make this only more confusing.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I understand what you mean. If they post on WPSE, then why should it be different for them if their post is migrated to another site? If it is confusing, then migrating to SO is confusing too. But for established users with over 3000 rep points (who can cast votes) I don't find this confusing.

Comment: Ah sorry, misread your question. I was thinking about the message shown to the users

Comment: This proposal has not received further attention? I totally agree that ServerFault should be an option for the "This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network" list, there are many questions related to apache/nginx configuration rather that WordPress itself. I don't think that SuperUser option should be present in that list.

Comment: BTW, ServerFault is listed under [help](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) section of WPSE.

Comment: @IvanShatsky Actually now there's a field when you are trying to close a question, it allows you to type and choose any site within the SE community.

Comment: @JackJohansson Oh it seems we are talking about different things. I don't have enough reputation to cast a close vote, the only thing I can do is to raise a flag, and there are no other choices except WPSE meta, StackOverflow or WebMasters: [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/zwAEIjn). Questions related to configuring server software are quite common on WPSE, [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/396165/can-i-redirect-one-specific-url-in-nginx) is the latest one which is definitely belongs to ServerFault site.